# pyscripter uncomment code shortcut

Tags: keyboard, comments, shortcut, pyscripter

Is there a keyboard shortcut for commenting out a selection of code in Pyscripter?

I'm using version 2.5.3.0 64 bit.

I've examined the interface and tried a few google searches, including a search on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the quote key

Will be used to comment selected lines and uncomment selected commented lines

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (comment) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (uncomment) like you did with PythonWin, you need to set up your own shortcuts.  Tools > Options > IDE Shortcuts..., then go to the Source Code Category and edit actEditCommentOut and actEditUncomment to whatever you want to use as keyboard shortcuts.  So relieved I finally figured this out, that silly "Toggle Comments" button was driving me nuts!  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

computer was not registering the  ctrl + " option. But i was able to change source code and it worked great.